# Firebase Null object Reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

When running updateList(), it works as it loads up the already-entered data from Firebase. This is a chat app so when someone types a message, Firebase updates in real time, which works as well.

The problem is I get a NullPointerException (Which shouldn't be the case) where I create a new Message object (Message mess = new Mess....). Why am I receiving this error and why is everything I tried not working?

Error = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference.

I tried a lock, a boolean, and tried making the variables global variables.

```
public void sendButtonClicked(View view) {

    final String messageValue = userMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    final String date = "4:20";
    final String userName = "Rob";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageValue)) {
            final DatabaseReference newPost = reference.push();
            newPost.child("Content").setValue(messageValue);
            newPost.child("Date").setValue(date);
            newPost.child("userName").setValue(userName);
        }
    }

private void updateList() {
    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Message mess = new Message(dataSnapshot.child("Content").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString(),dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString());
            result.add(mess);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(message);

            result.set(index, message);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(message);

            result.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Snapshot of how the data looks in Firebase

[FireBase Screesnhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU9dJ.png)

Comment: According to the Logcat the problem is when you call `toString()`.

Quite simply, the value in `dataSnapshot.child("Content").getValue()` is `NULL`, verify that this returns what you hope it returns.

Comment: I understand, but why? If the value was NULL, why would it still update the Firebase? Is it possible that the problem is that the onChildAdded method runs BEFORE the three values are pushed?

Comment: How do you initialize `reference`? I cannot see it in your code.

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();                  DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Messages");

Answer (score 0):

I think I was running into a similar issue and this response from Frank helped me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/-cdTDFBOmMw.

When you are creating the new record within Firebase, it looks like you are doing setValue() individually for each property:

```html
          newPost.child("Content").setValue(messageValue);
          newPost.child("Date").setValue(date);
          newPost.child("userName").setValue(userName);
```

So what is happening is the value for Date might be set which immediately triggers onChildAdded, but content is still missing. Try instead to set them as a single message object.